# How to compute composite score of rank order variables?

Tags: scales, ranking, ranks

I have several rank order items about the use of languages in different contexts. Specifically, respondents were asked to order three languages from  most to least used in situations such as at work, at school, when speaking with the parents, etc.

- How can I analyze the data?
- Can I compute some composite score to indicate the general language use for each respondent?

Comment: Please tell us a little about the objective of your analysis. What would you like to find out with these data?  What actions or decisions will be made as a result of your analysis?

Comment: Mainly, I want to see how use of language is related to attitudes, linguistic competencies and some demographic and background variables. Regarding the consequences of my thesis, I don't know yet what actions or decisions will follow, if any.